# sqlite advanced case sensitive query

Tags: sqlite

i search for a special kind of query in SQLite
to sort a notes table.

The result from the query should be like this:

```
id  oid
1    1
2    1,1
5    1,1,a
6    1,1,a,1
3    1,1,A
4    1,1,A,1
```

But with the folling code I receive this:

```
CREATE TABLE note (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
oid VARCHAR unique,
tit VARCHAR,
dsc VARCHAR
);

select id, oid from note
order by oid collate NOCASE
```

Result:

```
id  oid
1    1
2    1,1
5    1,1,a
3    1,1,A
6    1,1,a,1
4    1,1,A,1
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks
--jonah

Answer (score 2):

The following transforms the sort keys so that the normal case sensitive ordering yields the requested result:

If there was a `togglecase()` function, the function would uppercase lowercase and lowercase uppercase (for example `Hello` => `hELLO`), one could `ORDER BY togglecase(oid)` and the result would be in the order requested.

You could define such a function and expose it to SQLite as a UDF. It could also be possible to write this function using builtin SQLite functions but I don't know them well enough to give an answer using them. The following is an example of such a function in Python:

```
def togglecase(s):
   def toggle(l):
       if l.isupper(): 
           return l.lower()
       if l.islower():
           return l.upper()
       return l
   return ''.join(toggle(l) 
                  for l in s)
```

Note that for proper Unicode support it needs to iterate over graphemes. Not over code points.

See that this does what I described it to do:

```
>>> togglecase("1,1,A")
'1,1,a'
>>> togglecase("1,1,a")
'1,1,A'
```

It is possible to test if this sorts correctly in Python:

```
>>> sorted(["1", "1,1", "1,1,a", "1,1,a,1", "1,1,A", "1,1,A,1"])
['1', '1,1', '1,1,A', '1,1,A,1', '1,1,a', '1,1,a,1']
```

See how the uppercase follows the lowercase:

```
>> sorted(["1", "1,1", "1,1,a", "1,1,a,1", "1,1,A", "1,1,A,1"], key=togglecase)
['1', '1,1', '1,1,a', '1,1,a,1', '1,1,A', '1,1,A,1']
```

Now if you use it in SQLite like:

```
SELECT id, oid 
FROM note
ORDER BY togglecase(oid)
```

This should result in:

```
1   "1"
2   "1,1"
3   "1,1,a"
4   "1,1,a,1"
5   "1,1,A"
6   "1,1,A,1"
```

The code is untested except for the togglecase function.

Comment: Hi Dan, this might be a solution. Tanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that result because the sorting is pecified to be NOCASE. That means that "*a*" and "*A*" are equals. So, first the rows with "*a/A*" and nothing after, and then rows with "*a/A*" and data after.

If you make the query CASE SENSITIVE, you will get a different result. BUT "*A*" comes befores "*a*" in case sensitive sort:

```
SELECT id, oid 
FROM note
ORDER by oid
```

Results:

```
1   "1"
2   "1,1"
5   "1,1,A"
6   "1,1,A,1"
3   "1,1,a"
4   "1,1,a,1"
```